# Why is this USB linux install throwing errors?

Tags: boot, usb, linux-mint

I have a 32 bit compatible PC (dated 2005) currently running WinXP (that's why I'm trying to change OS) on which I'm trying to install linuxmint-18.1-cinnamon-32bit.iso

Not willing to burn a CD, I downloaded unetbootin and I used it to get the linux install in a "generic UDisk" USB key that passes the disk check.

I reboot, I press Del to enter the BIOS (v02.53 American Megatrends) and I...

1. Disable Quick Boot in order to see the UDisk
2. Change the boot order for Removable Drives to USB first

I reboot again and the options screen comes out.
I tried Default, Mint, Cinnamon 32bit, etc. but each gives me a list of errors, e.g.:

```
EDD: Error 0100 reading sector 1694
```

The Memory test oprion throws some of thes3e errors and then says "Cannot load a ramdisk with an old kernel image"

Comment: Your USB drive is probably broken. Try a different one.

Comment: Use `dd` on linux or `win32diskimager` on windows to create a bootable USB , Unetbootin may fail